# Making dynamic elements moveable in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css-selectors

I am using moveableJS to make the elements moveable. When I hardcode a div tag, it moves, as expected. But when I try to add a div tag dynamically, say on click of a button, the newly added div tag is not moveable.

Code modified from [here](https://daybrush.com/moveable/storybook/index.html?path=/story/basic--basic-draggable)

```jsx
import * as React from 'react';
import Moveable from 'react-moveable';
import './App.css';

export default function App() {
  const targetRef = React.useRef(null);
  const [box, setBox] = React.useState([]);

  function addBox() {
    setBox((prevboxes) => {
      return [...prevboxes, `target${box.length + 1}`];
    });
  }
  return (
    <div className="root">
      <button onClick={addBox}>Add box</button>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="target">Target</div>
        {box.map((boxElement) => {
          return (
            <div className="target" id={boxElement}>
              Target
            </div>
          );
        })}
        <Moveable
          target={['.target']}
          draggable={true}
          throttleDrag={1}
          edgeDraggable={false}
          startDragRotate={0}
          throttleDragRotate={0}
          onDrag={(e) => {
            e.target.style.transform = e.transform;
          }}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

My understanding is that Moveable is not able to recognise this element added later with className 'target'. How do I make it recognise this newly added element?

Comment: Try adding `key={box}` to the `Moveable` component so it re-renders when you add / remove boxes

Comment: Apparently there's an `updateSelectors()` method but I can't find any docs on how to integrate it with the React version

Comment: Did you tried to use `document.querySelector(".target")` instead of `['.target']`  in `target` property on `Moveable` component? Source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-moveable#-how-to-use